# GnuUEFI sprintf causes corrupted control flow

Tags: uefi, gnu-efi

I'm developing an UEFI program against GnuEFI (`-lefi -lgnuefi`). It is first compiled/linked as a shared object, then transformed into a EFI binary by objcopy (`objcopy -j .text -j .sdata -j .data -j .dynamic -j .dynsym  -j .rel -j .rela -j .reloc --target=efi-app-x86_64 in.so out.efi`). So far, everything works nicely but I now need `sprintf` and have reproducible crashes. Namely, when I do

```
char text[128];
sprintf(text, "foo");
```

This works fine, but as soon as I try

```
char text[128];
sprintf(text, "foo %d", 12345);
```

The program crashes. I am emulating using QEMU/OVMF and receive the following problem:

```
!!!! X64 Exception Type - 06(#UD - Invalid Opcode)  CPU Apic ID - 00000000 !!!!
RIP  - 0000000005F7E00C, CS  - 0000000000000038, RFLAGS - 0000000000000246
RAX  - 0000000000000000, RCX - 0000000005F7E260, RDX - 0000000000000100
RBX  - 0000000007EF59A0, RSP - 0000000007EF5970, RBP - 0000000005F7FED8
RSI  - 0000000000000001, RDI - 0000000007EFC3F0
R8   - 0000000000003039, R9  - 0000000000000000, R10 - 000000000000000A
R11  - 0000000000002328, R12 - 0000000007EF5B00, R13 - 0000000000FFFFFF
R14  - 0000000000000000, R15 - 0000000005F86018
DS   - 0000000000000030, ES  - 0000000000000030, FS  - 0000000000000030
GS   - 0000000000000030, SS  - 0000000000000030
CR0  - 0000000080010033, CR2 - 0000000000000000, CR3 - 0000000007801000
CR4  - 0000000000000668, CR8 - 0000000000000000
DR0  - 0000000000000000, DR1 - 0000000000000000, DR2 - 0000000000000000
DR3  - 0000000000000000, DR6 - 00000000FFFF0FF0, DR7 - 0000000000000400
GDTR - 00000000075DC000 0000000000000047, LDTR - 0000000000000000
IDTR - 000000000704F018 0000000000000FFF,   TR - 0000000000000000
FXSAVE_STATE - 0000000007EF55D0
!!!! Find image based on IP(0x5F7E00C) (No PDB)  (ImageBase=0000000005F72000, EntryPoint=0000000005F75000) !!!!
```

This is unsurprising because the IP actually points into my `.data` segment, i.e., it absolutely is no valid code there. But how does it end up there? Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Is there a sprintf method in gnuefi?

Comment: @MiSimon: It links, so there seems to be one. fpmurphy: Because Print is not what I want to do, I want to format a string.

Comment: If i build a gnuefi executable with sprintf, the symbol is undefined in the .so file. You can use UnicodeVSPrint from gnuefi as replacement.

Comment: There is a `SPrint` function for CHAR16 strings and an `AsciiVSPrint` for CHAR8 strings.